# Conflicting multiple application.yml on classpath

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have this project setup:

```
Spring-Boot-App 1:
src/main/resources/application.yml

Dependency-Spring-Boot-App-2.jar:
src/main/resources/application.yml
```

but the second *application.yml* gets ignored! Am I doing something wrong or is this default spring behaviour? How do I load the second *application.yml* so that all properties are avaiable to my app 1 ?

Comment: Two resources with exactly the same name on classpath. ClassLoader loads the first one.

Comment: your answer makes sense, yes, but this is spring boot, where you can forget the usual expectations

Comment: if you write an actual answer i can mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two resources with exactly the same name on classpath. ClassLoader loads the first one so the behavior is expected.